# "google spreadsheet" select range to fill the borders in scripteditor (simplify my code)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-editor

I have written some code to automatically fill the border lines.
The problem is that i want to use a specific range of cells based upon the position of the first empty cell.
I can get the code to work for a specific cell but not for a range.

please help me simplify the code

```
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');

  var cell =sheet.getRange(lastRow + 4, 2);
    cell.setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "black", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
  var cell =sheet.getRange(lastRow + 4, 3); 
    cell.setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "black", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
  var cell =sheet.getRange(lastRow + 4, 4);
    cell.setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "black", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);**
  var cell =sheet.getRange(lastRow + 5, 2);
    cell.setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "black", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
  var cell =sheet.getRange(lastRow + 5, 3); 
    cell.setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "black", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
  var cell =sheet.getRange(lastRow + 5, 4);
```

Comment: What is not working, specifically? What does this not do that you want it to do? How have you tried achieving your goal already? Are you familiar with JavaScript and the loop construct? (If not, you are expected to teach yourself with books, tutorials, examples, and such - we all did so you can too.)

Comment: It is working but i would like to simplify the code to something like:                   var cell =sheet.getRange((lastRow + 4, 2):(lastRow + 11,6));
    cell.setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, "black", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);

Comment: There are multiple method signatures available to `Sheet#getRange` - they should appear in the Script Editor autocomplete, and they are well-documented on the Apps Script documentation pages.

Comment: Thanks, i will look into that. Any advice for me on where i can start best to as you call it teach myself??

Comment: Thanks  to Tehhowch i've used following line and it works.                                          var cell =sheet.getRange(lastRow + 4, 2, 8, 6);

Comment: you can post your solution as an answer, including links to documentation for what you were originally using, and what you ended up using, to provide a resource to future site visitors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to tehhowch's help ended up with a solution to replace the code:

New code:

var cell =sheet.getRange(lastRow + 4, 2, 8, 6);